# Handling DBNull values for DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, collections

I'm converting my `DataTable` to generic List and as I'm converting row value to object for the list, it's giving Cast Exception. I've tried handling the DBNull using the code

```
if (dataRow["DateCompleted"] == DBNull.Value)
{
    dataRow["DateCompleted"] = null;
}
if (dataRow["TotalRecords"] == DBNull.Value)
{
    dataRow["TotalRecords"] = 0;
}
if (dataRow["CompanyName"] == DBNull.Value)
{
    dataRow["CompanyName"] = "";
}
```

but DateCompleted is not accepting the null, DBNull or empty string.

After the process, I'm making object like

```
DemoData demoValue = new DemoData
{
    CompanyName = dataRow["CompanyName"].ToString(),
    DateCompleted = (DateTime)dataRow["DateCompleted"],
    TotalRecords = (int)dataRow["TotalRecords"]
};
```

and adding the object to the list

```
DataList.Add(demoValue);
```

My list is

```
public List<DemoData> DataList = new List<DemoData>();
```

and my class is

```
public class DemoData
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCompleted { get; set; }
    public int TotalRecords { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I usually just use new DateTime() which will default date to Jan 1, 1900.  DateTime will not accept a null.

Comment: Try using `Nullable<DateTime>` or `DateTime?` for the `DateCompleted` field

Comment: @jdweng It's not feasible as in my application, Date & Time is important factor so can't set to default, it can be empty though

Comment: What is the difference between null and Jan 1,1900?  Jan 1, 1900 will never occur in real data and you can filter for DateTime > 2000 (or any real DateTime) to get rid of the Jan 1, 1900 dates.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Not useful, still giving exception

Comment: @jdweng It does appear in my data as I'm also using the archive table from the database, I can use max value instead

Comment: @jdweng But it'll still show in my GridView as If I wanted to filter the records, I would have skipped the row first time only

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on business logic you want to perform if `DemoData` is **not** completed:

You may want to insist on `null`; it makes, however, the logic more *complex* (since `null` is a *special case* now), and requires `DemoData` modification:

```
public class DemoData
{
     public string CompanyName { get; set; }
     // DateTime? - DateCompleted is Nullable<DateTime>   
     public DateTime? DateCompleted { get; set; }
     public int TotalRecords { get; set; }
}
...

DemoData demoValue = new DemoData {
  CompanyName = dataRow["CompanyName"].ToString(),
  DateCompleted = dataRow.IsDbNull("DateCompleted") 
    ? null // <- now we can assign null to Nullable<T>   
    : (DateTime?) dataRow["DateCompleted"],
  TotalRecords = (int)dataRow["TotalRecords"]
};
```

You may want to adopt the following (typical) logic: "If `DemoData` has *not* completed yet, it shall be *eventually* completed in a (distant) *future*":

```
...
if (dataRow["DateCompleted"] == DBNull.Value)
{
    // Well, at 31 Dec 9999 it'll be completed for sure...
    dataRow["DateCompleted"] = DateTime.MaxValue;
}

...

DemoData demoValue = new DemoData
{
  CompanyName = dataRow["CompanyName"].ToString(),
  DateCompleted = (DateTime)dataRow["DateCompleted"],
  TotalRecords = (int)dataRow["TotalRecords"]
};
```

Comment: It'll not be updated because the firm I work for is a data processing firm so the records are only maintained, not updated. So if I set it to MaxValue then it'll affect my data driven UI parts like Graph and GridView which I'm populating using this data itself.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out that the problem was I was assigning null values to the `dataRow` itself so it was not accepting any values, I wrote the code like this and now it's working fine

```
DateTime? dateCompleted;
if (dataRow["DateCompleted"] == DBNull.Value)
{
    dateCompleted= null;
}
else
{
    dateCompleted= (DateTime)dataRow["DateCompleted"];
}
DemoData demoValue = new DemoData
{
    CompanyName = dataRow["CompanyName"].ToString(),
    DateCompleted = dateCompleted,
    TotalRecords = (int)dataRow["TotalRecords"]
};
```

and for the class

```
public class DemoData
{
     public string CompanyName { get; set; }
     public DateTime? DateCompleted { get; set; }
     public int TotalRecords { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Make `DateCompleted` nullable in your class:

```
public class DemoData
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateCompleted { get; set; }
    public int TotalRecords { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It's giving exception `Cannot set Column 'DateCompleted' to be null. Please use DBNull instead.`

Comment: And when I'm using DBNull, it's giving an error like `Specified cast is not valid.` i.e InvalidCastException

Answer (score -1):

Since your source a a datatable try something like this

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("date", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns["date"].AllowDBNull = true;

            dt.Rows.Add();
            dt.Rows[0]["date"] = DBNull.Value;
```

Comment: It already have DBNull value, so I guess the `DataTable` is accepting DBNull value by default, there's no need to write it explicitly